# How is it possible that one achieved a fundamental gap that is lower than optical gap?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I know that the optical gap is generally lower than the fundamental gap, but when is the optical gap is lower than the fundamental gap?

Comment: It could be helpful, if you add a brief explanation of what is *fundamental gap* and the specific context where you encounter it (are you dealing with Kohn-Sham equations?)